# Binary detection problem with side information

Tags: probability

Assume we have an input random variable that takes values +1 or -1. And it goes through AWGN channel. The noise is gaussian distributed N(0,1). The output is Y1.

a) How do we find the probability X=1 or -1 based on the output Y
This would be based on Bayes rule and you decide on X=1 if Y>0.

b) If we have another random variable Y2=N1+N2 , can we use Y2 and Y1 together in some way additional information to make decision on X.
I am thinking of computing P(Y1Y2|X1) but I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes. Let $Y=X+Z$ with $P(X=1)=p$, $P(X=-1)=1-p$, $Z\perp X$ and $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Then $Y|X=x\sim\mathcal{N}(x,1)$:
$$P(X=1|Y=y)=\frac{f_{Y|X=1}(y)P(X=1)}{f_{Y|X=-1}(y)P(X=-1)+f_{Y|X=1}(y)P(X=1)}=\frac{pe^{-\frac{(y-1)^2}{2}}}{(1-p)e^{-\frac{(y+1)^2}{2}}+pe^{-\frac{(y-1)^2}{2}}}$$
b) Yes again. Let $Y_1=X+Z_1$ and $Y_2=X+Z_2$, with $P(X=1)=p$, $P(X=-1)=1-p$, $Z_1\perp Z_2\perp X$ and $Z_1,Z_2\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Then we can write
$$\binom{Y_1}{Y_2}=X\cdot\binom{1}{1}+\binom{Z_1}{Z_2}$$
Then $\binom{Y_1}{Y_2}|_{X=x}\sim\mathcal{N}_2\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\x\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)\right)$ (remain iid: $Y_1|_{X=x}\sim Y_2|_{X=x}\sim Y|_{X=x}$ ) and
\begin{align}
P(X=1|Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2)&=\frac{f_{Y|X=1}(y_1)f_{Y|X=1}(y_2)P(X=1)}{f_{Y|X=-1}(y_1)f_{Y|X=-1}(y_2)P(X=-1)+f_{Y|X=1}(y_1)f_{Y|X=1}(y_2)P(X=1)}\\
&=\frac{pe^{\frac{(y_1-1)^2}{2}-\frac{(y_2-1)^2}{2}}}{(1-p)e^{\frac{(y_1+1)^2}{2}-\frac{(y_2+1)^2}{2}}+pe^{\frac{(y_1-1)^2}{2}-\frac{(y_2-1)^2}{2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Matias. Actually for part b notice that y2=n1+n2. I appreciate your answer

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. What about N_1 and N_2? Any hypothesis related with X and Z?

Comment: So basically N_2 is another normal variable with mean 0 and variance 2. And now we have an output which is the sum of two noise. So how do use this output y1 and y2 to find x

Comment: but your output is only noise? or $Y_2=X+\mathcal{N}(0,2)$?

Comment: It's only noise your correct

Comment: But then is independent of $(X,Z)$. It will not do you any good to observe it (unless it is linked to Z); where $Y_1=X+Z$